# Trouble on parsing XML content into correct datatype in MATLAB

Tags: xml, matlab, xml-parsing

I am having difficulties wrapping my head around parsing an XML data into becoming a MATLAB struct.

Using the readily available [xml2struct](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct) function I was able to do just that. However, the final nodes has its contents as char, and I would like to have it as double, uint8, or whatever attributes that has been stated in the XML element.

Take for example this XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101" type="struct" size="1 1">
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price type="double">44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102" type="struct" size="1 1">
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price type="number" size="1 1">112</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I want to write a MATLAB code that can parse the above data into a struct but it would have the price for book one directly in the struct as double data type, and book two as uint8 data type, based on its attribute.

When that XML data is directly parsed using the function however, I will get for catalog.book{1,1}.price.Text the value of '44.95' as char.

Using the MATLAB function directly, it is possible to retrieve the attributes of the xml, but I'm confused on how to extend the function in xml2struct in order to convert the data type content such as the price according to the attribute of the element.

**Can anyone help me by hinting where exactly I can manipulate the XML content to change its datatype in the function?** I've done step by step debugging, just to see exactly how the function works, but I still can't seem to find the solution...

Below is the full xml2struct function code:

```
function [ s ] = xml2struct( file )
%Convert xml file into a MATLAB structure
% [ s ] = xml2struct( file )
%
% A file containing:
% <XMLname attrib1="Some value">
%   <Element>Some text</Element>
%   <DifferentElement attrib2="2">Some more text</DifferentElement>
%   <DifferentElement attrib3="2" attrib4="1">Even more text</DifferentElement>
% </XMLname>
%
% Will produce:
% s.XMLname.Attributes.attrib1 = "Some value";
% s.XMLname.Element.Text = "Some text";
% s.XMLname.DifferentElement{1}.Attributes.attrib2 = "2";
% s.XMLname.DifferentElement{1}.Text = "Some more text";
% s.XMLname.DifferentElement{2}.Attributes.attrib3 = "2";
% s.XMLname.DifferentElement{2}.Attributes.attrib4 = "1";
% s.XMLname.DifferentElement{2}.Text = "Even more text";
%
% Please note that the following characters are substituted
% '-' by '_dash_', ':' by '_colon_' and '.' by '_dot_'
%
% Written by W. Falkena, ASTI, TUDelft, 21-08-2010
% Attribute parsing speed increased by 40% by A. Wanner, 14-6-2011
% Added CDATA support by I. Smirnov, 20-3-2012
%
% Modified by X. Mo, University of Wisconsin, 12-5-2012

    if (nargin < 1)
        clc;
        help xml2struct
        return
    end

    if isa(file, 'org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl') || isa(file, 'org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl')
        % input is a java xml object
        xDoc = file;
    else
        %check for existance
        if (exist(file,'file') == 0)
            %Perhaps the xml extension was omitted from the file name. Add the
            %extension and try again.
            if (~contains(file,'.xml'))
                file = [file '.xml'];
            end

            if (exist(file,'file') == 0)
                error(['The file ' file ' could not be found']);
            end
        end
        %read the xml file
        xDoc = xmlread(file);
    end

    %parse xDoc into a MATLAB structure
    s = parseChildNodes(xDoc);

end

% ----- Subfunction parseChildNodes -----
function [children,ptext,textflag] = parseChildNodes(theNode)
    % Recurse over node children.
    children = struct;
    ptext = struct; textflag = 'Text';
    if hasChildNodes(theNode)
        childNodes = getChildNodes(theNode);
        numChildNodes = getLength(childNodes);

        for count = 1:numChildNodes
            theChild = item(childNodes,count-1);
            [text,name,attr,childs,textflag] = getNodeData(theChild);
            %[text,name,childs,textflag] = getNodeData(theChild);

            if (~strcmp(name,'#text') && ~strcmp(name,'#comment') && ~strcmp(name,'#cdata_dash_section'))
                %XML allows the same elements to be defined multiple times,
                %put each in a different cell
                if (isfield(children,name))
                    if (~iscell(children.(name)))
                        %put existsing element into cell format
                        children.(name) = {children.(name)};
                    end
                    index = length(children.(name))+1;
                    %add new element
                    children.(name){index} = childs;
                    if(~isempty(fieldnames(text)))
                        children.(name){index} = text; 
                    end
                    %if(~isempty(attr)) 
                    %    children.(name){index}.('Attributes') = attr; 
                    %end
                else
                    %add previously unknown (new) element to the structure
                    children.(name) = childs;
                    if(~isempty(text) && ~isempty(fieldnames(text)))
                        children.(name) = text; 
                    end
                    if(~isempty(attr)) 
                        children.(name).('Attributes') = attr; 
                    end
                end
            else
                ptextflag = 'Text_Me';
                if (strcmp(name, '#cdata_dash_section'))
                    ptextflag = 'CDATA';
                elseif (strcmp(name, '#comment'))
                    ptextflag = 'Comment';
                end

                %this is the text in an element (i.e., the parentNode) 
                if (~isempty(regexprep(text.(textflag),'[\s]*','')))
                    if (~isfield(ptext,ptextflag) || isempty(ptext.(ptextflag)))
                        ptext.(ptextflag) = text.(textflag);
                    else
                        %what to do when element data is as follows:
                        %<element>Text <!--Comment--> More text</element>

                        %put the text in different cells:
                        % if (~iscell(ptext)) ptext = {ptext}; end
                        % ptext{length(ptext)+1} = text;

                        %just append the text
                        ptext.(ptextflag) = [ptext.(ptextflag) text.(textflag)];
                    end
                end
            end

        end
    end
end

 % ----- Subfunction getNodeData -----
function [text,name,attr,childs,textflag] = getNodeData(theNode)
    % Create structure of node info.

    %make sure name is allowed as structure name
    name = toCharArray(getNodeName(theNode))';
%     name = strrep(name, '-', '_dash_');
%     name = strrep(name, ':', '_colon_');
%     name = strrep(name, '.', '_dot_');

    attr = parseAttributes(theNode);
    if (isempty(fieldnames(attr))) 
       attr = []; 
    end

    %parse child nodes
    [childs,text,textflag] = parseChildNodes(theNode);

    if (isempty(fieldnames(childs)) && isempty(fieldnames(text)))
        %get the data of any childless nodes
        % faster than if any(strcmp(methods(theNode), 'getData'))
        % no need to try-catch (?)
        % faster than text = char(getData(theNode));
        text.(textflag) = toCharArray(getTextContent(theNode))';
    end

end

% ----- Subfunction parseAttributes -----
function attributes = parseAttributes(theNode)
    % Create attributes structure.

    attributes = struct;
    if hasAttributes(theNode)
       theAttributes = getAttributes(theNode);
       numAttributes = getLength(theAttributes);

       for count = 1:numAttributes
%             attrib = item(theAttributes,count-1);
%             attr_name = regexprep(char(getName(attrib)),'[-:.]','_');
%             attributes.(attr_name) = char(getValue(attrib));

            %Suggestion of Adrian Wanner
            str = toCharArray(toString(item(theAttributes,count-1)))';
            k = strfind(str,'='); 
            attr_name = str(1:(k(1)-1));
%             attr_name = strrep(attr_name, '-', '_dash_');
%             attr_name = strrep(attr_name, ':', '_colon_');
%             attr_name = strrep(attr_name, '.', '_dot_');
            attributes.(attr_name) = str((k(1)+2):(end-1));
       end
    end
end
```

EDIT: I've found the answer. To change the attribute, we should add apply the changes in the getNodeData subfunction. Specifically adding this block of conditional after the calling of parseChildNode within.

```
%parse child nodes
[childs,text,textflag] = parseChildNodes(theNode);

if isfield(attr, 'type')
    switch attr.type
        case 'double'
            text.(textflag) = str2double(strsplit(text.(textflag)));
        case 'int'
            text.(textflag) = str2number(strsplit(text.(textflag)));
    end
end
```

Comment: I would not modify the source code of that file. Why not simply convert those nodes to double after the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need convert data types depending on the Attributes.type values of price.

Below is a sample codes with xml2struct. It checks the field of Attributes.type of each price property and converts the data type depending on the type ("number" or "double"). By default, MATLAB treats numeric value as double, so price 112 would be treated as double by converting with str2double. I think double is fine, but if you want to treat it as uint8, please use uint8(str2double(price.Text)).

```
xmlhandler = xml2struct('yourXmlFile.xml');
books = xmlhandler.catalog.book;

for ii=1:size(books, 2)
    eachBook = books{1, ii};
    price = eachBook.price;
    if isfield(price.Attributes, 'type')
        dataType = price.Attributes.type;

        % Add Value property depending on the data type
        switch dataType
            case 'number'
                books{1, ii}.price.Value = uint8(str2double(price.Text));
                %eachBook.price.Value = str2double(price.Text); % If double is fine
            case 'double'
                books{1, ii}.price.Value = str2double(price.Text);
            otherwise
                % Do something if type is not specified
        end
    end
end
```

The above sample codes added Value property to price, but just replacing Text property, please do like `books{1, ii}.price.Text = str2double(price.Text)`.